# Push values from cookie to a multiple select in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a multiple select object in my html and I want to set up the cookies so that whenever I reload the website, I get the selected values from the last session.

In order to set up the cookies, I have used the following javascript code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(document.cookie.length != 0){
        var nameValuearray = document.cookie.split("=");
        list_values_selected=nameValuearray[1].split(",");
        document.getElementById("ms_example2_sinB").value= list_values_selected;
    }
}

function  getvaluecookie(){
var d = new Date();
    <!--Se define el tiempo en el que expirará la cookie-->
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (360*24*3600*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    <!--Se obtiene la lista de valores seleccionados-->
    var selectedflavor = $("#ms_example2_sinB").val();

    if (selectedflavor!="None selected"){
        document.cookie= "flavor=" + selectedflavor + ";" + expires;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn´t work as I want it to work. The cookie is correctly generated but I cannot manage to push the values from the list list_values_selected as selected values in the dropdown.

The html code is:

```
<form  name="prueba_sin_B" method="POST" action="/" onsubmit="getvaluecookie()">
            <select multiple  id="ms_example2_sinB" name="select" >
                    <option value="Cheese" >Cheese</option>
                    <option value="tomatoes" >Tomatoes</option>
                    <option value="mozarella" >Mozzarella</option>
                    <option value="mushrooms" >Mushrooms</option>
                    <option value="pepperoni" >Pepperoni</option>
                    <option value="onions" >Onions</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
        </div>
    </form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Icanps and welcome to SO. `<!--` are HTML comments, your script will definitely fail there. Use `// I am a comment` or `/* I am a comment */` to create comments in JS. Be sure to check the console in your browser for any errors when your script does not run. It will give you detailed information about your JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

To make the options selected in multiselect, you have to set each option's `selected` property to `true`
Use below code for `window.onload`

```js
window.onload = function(){
    if(document.cookie.length != 0){
        var nameValuearray = document.cookie.split("=");
        list_values_selected=nameValuearray[1].split(",");
        $.each(list_values_selected, function(i,e){
            $("#ms_example2_sinB option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Liju! This is exactly what i needed.